# Matlab TCP/IP Server Sockets not sending accurate data

Tags: matlab, tcp

I am using the example from the Matlab R2019A documentation about TCP/IP connection to send data back and forth two Matlab instances over TCP.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/communicate-using-tcpip-server-sockets.html

I have a TCP client (client.m) file written as:

```matlab
    data = sin(1:64);
    plot(data);
    t = tcpip('localhost', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
    fopen(t)
    fwrite(t, data)
```

and a TCP server (server.m) file written as:

```matlab
    t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
    fopen(t);
    data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
    plot(data);
```

However, the data being sent from the client is a `double` array, but the data received is a `integer` array.

The data sent looks like the following plot:
[image: Data Sent]
While the data received looks like the following plot:
[image: Data Received]

How can I ensure that the data that is being sent is received exactly as it is?

Comment: Not possible. What you send is what you receive. Check your assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do, is to specify also the precision of the data being send and received (to ensure the bytes are interpreted correctly):

```
% to send 
fwrite(t, data, 'double');

% to receive 1000 doubles
data = fread(t, 1000, 'double');
```

This is at least what Mathworks suggests. See [section](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/read-and-write-binary-data-over-tcpip.html) `Reading binary data`, as well as docs for [fread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/fread.html) and [fwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/fwrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening - turns out the Mathworks documentation was incorrect.

Since we're sending data as doubles, you'll need to specify the data being sent to be encoded as doubles. When reading it back, remember to account for the fact that eight bytes represent one double.

Here's how the client code needed to be changed to:

```
fwrite(t, data, 'double');
```

Here's how the server receives it as doubles:

```
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable/8, 'double');
```

You need the `t.BytesAvailable/8` to ensure that eight bytes are being interpreted as one value.

Comment: The second argument to `fread()` is the number of values (doubles in your case) to be read, which means that the number of bytes read is equal to the `number of values`(=second argument) times `precision`(3rd argument). `t.BytesAvailable` is the number of bytes currently available in the input buffer. So naturally it has to be divided by the number of bytes of a double.

Comment: The downside to this is, that you only read as many values as are currently available in the input buffer. To read a variable amount of values (the receiver might not know how much data is being send) try to make use of the `timeout` property of the tcpclient connection. So you can read all data received in a certain amount of time.