# How to send a list of doubles as a client TCP in c++ to a TCP server in Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, tcp, raspberry-pi

I am new to c++ and Matlab, I want to send some data from a raspberry pi to my Matlab. This data is a list of doubles. That is the code I have so far.
C++ (Client):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    double x[] = {10, 13.878, 3.09, 43, 5.0, 2, 342.42, 4};
    send(sock, x, sizeof(x), 0);
    close(sock);
    printf("Message sent\n"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Matlab (server):

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 8080, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
data = 0;
while(data ~= 1)
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
disp(data);
end
disp("fim do codigo");
fclose(t);
```

The output in the Matlab is:

```
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
    36
    64
   168
   198
    75
    55
   137
   193
    43
    64
   184
    30
   133
   235
    81
   184
     8
    64
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
   128
    69
    64
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
    20
    64
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
    64
    31
   133
   235
    81
   184
   102
   117
    64
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
    16
    64

Error using icinterface/fread (line 160)
SIZE must be greater than 0.

Error in servidor (line 5)
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
```

The list in the C++ code is just a test and it was received in the Matlab with the wrong numbers. Can someone help me send this list correctly?

EDIT:

I tried changing my `fread` command to `data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable, 'double=>double');` as suggested below, but it did not work, `'double=>double'` is not the correct name, I tried only `'double'` instead of `'double=>double'`. The new output is:

```
    Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.
'tcpip' unable to read all requested data. For more information on possible reasons, see TCPIP Read Warnings. 
   1.0e-37 *

   -0.0000
   -0.2242
    0.0000
    0.0000

Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.
'tcpip' unable to read any data. For more information on possible reasons, see TCPIP Read Warnings. 
fim do codigo
```

Another thing I changed was the size of the list, now I am only trying to send this list: `double x[4] = {13.878, 3.09, 5.0, 342.42};`

Comment: The linked answer I think will solve your problem: `data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable/8, 'double');`. If you have `N` bytes available, then you can read `N/8` doubles. Let me know if this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Another thing to change: `while(data ~= 1)` makes no sense, `data` is the array of values read. Instead do something like `while t.BytesAvailable > 0`. But it would probably be better to rely on the `TimeOut` property instead: https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpip.html#mw_a66421c8-88ec-4743-9eef-62f38a889cfc

Comment: @CrisLuengo the last warning message is gone now, but the numbers I receive is the same as before

Comment: Ok, I’ll reopen the question then. Please edit it to remove the issue with the warning message, so it can be focused on the correctness of the numbers. For future reference, the linked Q&A was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632576/matlab-tcp-ip-server-sockets-not-sending-accurate-data

Comment: you are receiving bytes of data one by one. It takes 8 bytes (64 bits) to represent a `double` number. So collect your bytes, when you have enough, convert them into an actual `double`. The function [`typecast`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) is your friend!

Answer (score -1):

By default fread interprets bytes. So according to the fread documentation you should use something like:

```
d = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable, 'double=>double');
```

Hope this helps,